# Did Jesus' body stay warm in the tomb?

Tags: catholicism, life-of-jesus, gospel-of-john

We read in Jn 19: 39-40 how the body of Jesus was prepared for burial :

> Nicodemus brought a mixture of myrrh and aloes, about seventy-five pounds. Taking Jesus’ body, the two of them wrapped it, with the spices, in strips of linen. This was in accordance with Jewish burial customs.

In Jn 20: 6-7 we come across the scenario immediately after the Resurrection:

> Then Simon Peter came along behind him (John)  and went straight into the tomb. He saw the strips of linen lying there,  as well as the cloth that had been wrapped around Jesus’ head. The cloth was still lying in its place, separate from the linen.

We do not find any  mention of the spices which had been applied to the body of Jesus . As per the narration in Jn 19: 39, the spices weighed 34.019 kilograms which would easily be visible ,  fallen apart, since a cold dead  body is least likely to absorb spices. But in case the body remained warm, there is the possibility that the spices got evaporated. John's way of not mentioning the presence of  residue of spices applied to Jesus'body , after his resurrection , leads one to the speculation that  the body  remained warm in the tomb .  My question therefore,  is: According to Catholic scholars, did Jesus'body stay warm in the tomb ?

Answer (score 2):

**Did Jesus' body stay warm in the tomb?**

The short answer is **no**!

Christians , including Catholics, believe that Jesus truly died on the Cross.

It is hard to speak of Our Lord’s body as in being a cadaver. But, the reality is that for the duration that his body was in the tomb his body would have cooled down until it (his body) reached the ambient temperature of the tomb. There was no life force left in his body to maintain the temperature of the human body while living, [98.6°F (37°C)](https://medlineplus.gov/ency/article/001982.htm).

Where or not the body of Jesus Christ started to decompose is another question, that is not addressed here and I will not answer either in this post.

> After death, the metabolic rate of the body decreases. Although certain metabolic reactions are still occurring in the body, it’s no longer making new molecules or generating any energy.
>
> Without the brain and heart functioning, there’s no way for the body to control its temperature. Therefore, based on the laws of physics, the temperature of the corpse will equilibrate with the surrounding ambient temperature. If the temperature is below 37°C, the body temperature will decrease by 1°C in the first two hours after death, and then continue to decrease by one degree every hour. - [What Is Algor Mortis?](https://www.scienceabc.com/pure-sciences/what-is-algor-mortis-definition-stage-of-death.html)

Unfortunately the spices that may have been applied to the body of the Lord Jesus would have no affect on the ***algor mortis***.

Our Lord truly died, but he is now truly risen!